# Eating a big meal around a weightlifting workout - before or after?

Tags: weightlifting, nutrition

When is the best time to eat a big meal when weight training - before or after the workout? Also how much time before or after is optional / beneficial?

Comment: If you type in "eating before or after exercise" in the search box you will find multiple questions and answers to give you the info you need.

Answer (score 2):

before most definatedly, when you don't eat u can't lift heavy

when you eat to soon you'll probably feel bloated and not strong enough due to the increased energy it takes to process the food.

for me an hour before is the magic timing, and I also recommend eating fat meals because it gives energy for a longer time

Comment: Many articles advocate eating something before and after weightlifting. This is to maximize muscle gains and prevent the body from burning muscles for fuel. Personally, it's irrelevant when big meals are eaten as long as the body has enough energy for the exercises to be had.

Comment: very true, although I sometimes have trouble getting a appetite after a serious lifting session so that's I focus more on the time before session. Not eating after will result in minimal gains obviouly

Comment: Personally I always eat right after weight lifting, I must feed my muscle within 45mins after workout.